# Efficient way of transforming an array of objects

Tags: javascript, arrays, dictionary, stream

I have following data structure that I get from some api:

```
response = [{grade: 'A', frequency: 54, percentage: 24},
      {grade: 'B', frequency: 50, percentage: 10},
      {grade: 'C', frequency: 0, percentage: 0},
      {grade: 'D', frequency: 50, percentage: 20},
      ...
    ];
```

Now some UI javascript library requires this data to be formatted and presented as follows:

```
label: ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D'];
data: [[54,50,0,50],[24,10,0,20]];
series: ['frequency', 'percentage'];
```

What would be the most efficient way to convert the **response** object to the above elements?

```
let label = response.map(data => data.grade);
let freqencyData = response.map(data => data.freqency);
let percentageData = response.map(data => data.percentage);
let data = [freqencyData, percentageData];
```

Would something like this this be efficient enough? Please not that this is an example and the response data in my case is too big and having the map done three times seems to be an overkill.
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the function `reduce` to build the almost desired output in one loop.

1. Separate the `label` attribute with the rest of the attributes.
2. Group the values by the specific property-name (data, label, and series).
3. The Object `Set` allows you to keep unique strings for the `series`.
4. `Object.from` converts the object `Set` to Array.
5. `Object.values` extracts from this: `{frequency: [1,2,3], percentage: [1,2,3]}` to this: `[[1,2,3], [1,2,3]]`

```js
let response = [{grade: 'A', frequency: 54, percentage: 24},{grade: 'B', frequency: 50, percentage: 10},{grade: 'C', frequency: 0, percentage: 0},{grade: 'D', frequency: 50, percentage: 20}];
let result = response.reduce((a, {grade: label, ...rest}) => {
  Object.keys(rest).forEach(k => {
    (a.series || (a.series = new Set())).add(k);
    a.data = a.data || {};
    (a.data[k] || (a.data[k] = [])).push(rest[k]);
  });  
  (a.label || (a.label = [])).push(label);
  
  return a;
}, Object.create(null));

result.series = Array.from(result.series);
result.data = Object.values(result.data);

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 0):

You could just do an old fashioned loop:

```
let label = [];
let freqencyData = [];
let percentageData = [];

response.forEach(function(element) {
  label.push(data.grade);
  frequencyData.push(data.frequency);
  percentageData.push(data.percentage);
});

let data = [freqencyData, percentageData];
```